Understanding a method of evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2+n} \right)^{n^2 + \sqrt{n}}$

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2+n} \right)^{n^2 + \sqrt{n}}$$
(A) $\;e\quad$ (B) $\;1\quad$ (C) $\;0\quad$ (D) $\;\infty$

Found this ina question bank for a competitive exam.Tried for a while, but couldn't understand and then referred a video. I didn't get the procedure used in this YouTube video by Mathsmerizing (time code: 36.21), which obtains answer (A). Please check the video and help me with an explanation.
Also share alternative methods if possible.

Take log of the limit

Please describe the procedure given in video. Don't request users to look at videos.

Sorry, that explanation was too brief that I couldn't understand it when I posted it.

Hey @aut I read the reply section of that post. That person was really rude. I'll try to explain what Taylor series is. Have you learnt of derivatives?

:( one more interested person lost. I hate few people in this community. Wish I could explain you

Try to multiply and divide the exponent by $n^2+n$ and then use some well-known limit, translating the problem to the limit of a quotient of polynomials.

i was trying that method and solved one part. Feels like I'm stranded again

Which part did you solve? The base of the exponential can be reduced to a textbook limit, can you recognize which one? While the exponent is the quotient of two polynomials of degree two, what do you know about the limit of the quotient of two polynomials of the same degree?

i tried to split it to $n^2 +n$ so that the limit tends to infinity for that part, correct me if i'm wrong. I'm not really good with this.

If possibleshare with me some similar questions with less complexity, so that I can understand

Don't worry, with practice you will learn! :) Now, we have to deal with two separate problems. The "base" is $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)^{n^2+n}$, while the "exponent" is $\frac{n^2+\sqrt{n}}{n^2+n}$, are we on the same page with this?

Got it... I understood now. But how to go further
If I'm right now we have $e^{(n^2+n^0.5)/n^2+n}$ where limit tends to 0, right?

Let's call the first of the two sequences $L$, and $M$ the second. You now have to compute the limit of $L^M$, right? By a theorem of Calculus, if both limits exist (and in particular, here they are finite), the limit of the exponent $L^M$ is the exponentiation of the limits of $L$ and $M$, so if we can compute the two limits separately, we are done. Does this make sense?

I almost got the answer, but I need more reference with the theorem we are discussing. Thanks for your effort.

Many textbooks refer to these kinds of theorems as "the Algebra of Limits", because they explain how to compute the limit of the sum (i.e. the sum of the limits), the limit of the products,... and other algebraic operations. Here's an explanation that I like:
https://www.sfu.ca/math-coursenotes/Math%20157%20Course%20Notes/sec_ComputingLimitsAlg.html

Do you mean the division rule?

Please see if I got it right, we break down a part of the base to euler's number. Then we limit the exponent by dividing the limit of numerator by denominator which is 1. And hence the solution is e.

The base narrows down to Euler's number, yes, this is correct. For the exponent, I am not sure about what you mean by "dividing the limits". Just factor out from both the numerator and the denominator the term $n^2$ and compute the rest. This will converge to 1 as you say.

Hint
$$A= \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2+n} \right)^{n^2 + \sqrt{n}}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(A)=\left(n^2+\sqrt{n}\right) \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$$
Use Taylor series for the logarithm, simplify and re-exponentiate since $A=e^{\log(A)}$

can you share more about the method. Like a similar question. I'm not familiar with it.

@aut. Use at least $\log(1+\epsilon)\sim \epsilon$ and you are almost done
